# custom authentication not working in django-tastypie

Tags: python, django, authentication, tastypie

My question is, how do i write my own custom authentication correctly??

i have tried to follow this: 
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication.html#implementing-your-own-authentication-authorization

I have implemented basic method,

**api.py**

```
def prepareResponce(responceData):
    """Prepares a Json responce with status 200"""
    response = JsonResponse(responceData)
    return response  # {"foo": "bar"}

class CustomBasicAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):
    userID = None
    userType = None
    userAccess = None
    userName = None

    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        if 'admin' in request.user.username:
             return prepareResponce({'logged in': 'Admin' })
                  #return True
        return prepareResponce({'not allowed for':userName })


    def get_identifier(self, request):
        return request.user.username


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        authentication = CustomBasicAuthentication()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
```

when i call API providing admin's username and password it's always return the else part. **where am i did wrong ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `return` and You don't call parent `is_authenticated` function:

```
def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
    super(CustomBasicAuthentication, self).is_authenticated(request, **kwargs)
    if 'admin' == request.user.username:
         return prepareResponce({'logged in': 'Admin' })
    return prepareResponce({'not allowed for': self.userName })
```